# Really stop Apache 2.4 from running on Yosemite

Tags: apache-http-server, osx-yosemite

I tried to start and stop Apache, I tried to stop Apache twice to make sure I should have been stopped

```
Mac-mini:~ jeud$ sudo apachectl start
Mac-mini:~ jeud$ sudo apachectl stop
Mac-mini:~ jeud$ sudo apachectl stop
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

But it seems that I still can access to Apache web server using `http://localhost`, `http://127.0.0.1` from the web browser, I still get response from `Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.2`

I tried `sudo lsof -i -P | grep 80`

```
httpd      554           root    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      555           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      566           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      567           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      568           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      569           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      570           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      571           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      603           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      605           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd      746           _www    5u  IPv6 0x8b96aa4ecd4e340b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

How to really stop Apache from running, please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
which apachectl
```

on my mavericks I get

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

then

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
```

Comment: after upgrading to El Capitain, I get the result:  `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service`   (and the .plist file exists for what that's worth)

Comment: I had the same problem on El Capitan and only way I could get it to stop was this sudo killall httpd